# Remove ActionBar in API below 11

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I got few `Activities` that use `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"` as theme. **API** levels above **11** work without a problem, but when I set my `minimumSdkVerison` to `"8"` in manifest it tells me that it requires **API** level **13**.

If I understood correct there is no `ActionBar` or "Theme.Holo" in **API** levels below **8**, so there will be no `ActionBar` by default, but however if I leave  `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"` out then in **API** levels above **11** my `Activities` will have the `ActionBar`. Is there any simple way to get rid of `ActionBar` in all the `Activities`? I tried using Sherlock ActionBar, but found it too complicated for my needs, as I only want to get rid of `ActionBar` above **API 11** devices.

Comment: There's also no `Theme.Holo` before API Lvl 11.

Comment: If you get rid of `Theme.Holo` you will get rid of your requirement for lvl 11. If you want to keep Holo you'd have to use ActionBarSherlock. It's not that complicated, especially if you're not doing too much customization AND you don't want an ActionBar.

Comment: All I want is to disable ActionBar from all my activities in all API levels. Theme.Holo was just an example. Theme really doesnt matter as long as ActionBar is gone.

Comment: Sure, then just use the base Light theme then :)

Comment: i tried it but it messed up my preference activity

Comment: So maybe you DID care about Holo :D, you just didn't know it. All features should work the same, just have the old look. In theory. Not sure what "messed up my pref activity" means exactly, but you might want to open a new question for that.

Comment: Well after removing app completely and reinstalling it, problem seems to be dissappeared. But thanks for information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a new project with the Eclipse wizard, it creates the theme `AppTheme` for you, which inherits from `AppBaseTheme`. This theme is replaced depending on the API Level. So you can use `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` as your default theme and `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` from API Level 11 upwards.

If you don't care about using Holo, just use `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` as your theme.

Comment: I tried that, but it messes up my preference activity. And lists are empty

Comment: is there any other older themes without action bar?

Comment: @RohitMalish All themes without Holo in the name.

Comment: can I find a list of those somewhere?

Comment: @RohitMalish Have a look at platforms/android-17/data/res/values/themes.xml in your android install directory or here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Answer (score 2):

To fix that that use AppCompat support library and add this code to the activity you don't want to show Actiobar in the AndroidManifest file

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```